# self-adjoint problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a self-adjoint linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space.
> Given a vector $ y \in (KerT)^\bot$,prove there exists a unique vector $x\in(KerT)^\bot$,such that $Tx=y$.

I know that if quesion is $Ty=x$ then take $a\in KerT$ $\langle a,x\rangle=\langle a,Ty\rangle =\langle Ta,y\rangle=0$ 

but I have no idea about $Tx=y$

Please give me some hint,Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us show first that $(ran T)^\perp = ker T$. Indeed, if $x\in(ran T)^\perp$, then for all $u$ we have $(Tx,u) = (x,Tu) = 0$ since $Tu\in ran T$. Thus, $Tx = 0$, i.e., $x\in ker T$. Conversely, let $x\in ker T$. Then $(x,Tu) = (Tx,u) = 0$ for all $u$ and hence $x\in (ran T)^\perp$.

Now, applying the orthogonal complement to $(ran T)^\perp = ker T$, we obtain $ran T = (\ker T)^\perp$, which is equivalent to $H = ker T\oplus ran T$ (where $H$ is the inner product space).

If $y\in (ker T)^\perp$ as in your question, this means that $y\in ran T$, i.e., there exists $x'$ such that $y = Tx'$. Since $H = ker T\oplus ran T$ we can write $x' = u + x$ with $u\in ker T$ and $x\in ran T$. Hence, $y = Tx' = T(u+x) = Tu + Tx = Tx$. Suppose there is another $\hat x\in ran T$ with $T\hat x = y$. Then $T(x-\hat x) = Tx-T\hat x = y-y = 0$, i.e., $x-\hat x\in ker T\cap ran T = \{0\}$, that is, $\hat x = x$.

Comment: got it ,thank for your help!!

Comment: Please check my answer, and - if you liked it - upvote it. Thanks.