# Prove that every vector from $R(A)$ is picture of only one vector from $R(A^{T})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-algorithm

Let matrix $A$ is a record of some linear transformation $A:U\to V$. Prove that every vector from $R(A)$ is picture of exactly one vector from $R(A^{T})$.

Suppose the opposite, let $w\in R(A)$ is picture of two vector $x,y \in R(A^{T})$, then $w=Ax$, $w=Ay$, and $x=A^{T}a$ and $y=A^{T}b$ where $a,b \in V$  than we can write $AA^{T}a=w$ and $AA^{T}b=w$, if matrices $A$ is orthogonal than it is easy to prove, but what if it not? I have no idea how to prove

Comment: Show that $R(A)^\perp = ker(A^T)$ (and thus $R(A^T) = ker(A)^\perp$). This is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890068/self-adjoint-problem/2890128#2890128

Comment: @amsmath thank you

Comment: @amsmath Can you check this? Because I know that $U=N(A)\oplus R(A^{T})$. Now suppose the opposite, let $w\in R(A)$ is picture of two vector $x,y\in R(A{T})$, then $w=Ax, w=Ay$, since $x,y\in U$, then we can write $x=x1+x2,y=y1+y2$, where $x1,y1\in N(A)$ and $x2,y2\in R(A^{T})$, then we write $w=Ax1+Ax2$, and $w=Ay1+Ay2$. and $A(x1+x2-y1-y2)=w-w=0$, then $(x1-y1)\in N(A)$ and $(x2-y2)\in R(A^{T})$ from here I confused because who guarantee that $(x1-y1)$ and $(x2-y2)$ is $\in N(A)\cap R(A^{T})$ and then $x1-y1=0$ and $x2-y2=0$ from here $x=y$.

Comment: Ok, you start with $Ax = Ay = w$. This implies $A(x-y) = 0$, i.e., $x-y\in N(A)$. But $x-y\in R(A^T)$ and thus $x-y = 0$ (since the sum $U = N(A)\oplus R(A^T)$ is direct.